# Capacidad máxima de String en C#

Tags: c#, string

!Buenas!

Tengo un fragmento de código sencillo que no logro entender muy bien lo que esta pasando...

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string cadena = "lore";

        for(int i=0; i<1000000; i++)
        {
            cadena += "lore";
        }
        Console.WriteLine(cadena);
    }
```

Lo que realiza es sencillo de averiguar. Simplemente concadenada **un millón** de veces la palabra `lore` en la variable `cadena` y después **la debería** de  mostrar por consola.

Resalto el **debería** porque no lo hace. Y esto es lo que no entiendo, ¿por que no muestra el resultado, y mantiene el programa en ejecución? ¿Y como puedo hacer que lo muestre?

He intentado darle una vuelta... Y la lógica que le encuentro es que sobrepasa el limite de caracteres que puede tener un `string`, pero como no salta ningún tipo de excepción me hace dudar.

**¿Alguna idea de por que pasa esto, y de como solucionarlo?**

Comment: pero obtienes un Exception ? digo si defines un try..catch sale por error

Comment: Has probado a esperar? ten en cuenta que un bucle tan largo puede colapsar y tardar bastante, aparte el tamaño máximo de un string es [1,073,741,823](https://stackoverflow.com/a/140749/10053314)

Comment: sino sale por error quiere decir que aun esta ejecutando

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sospecho que el problema no es el tamaño máximo que admite un `string` en .net (teoricamente 2,147,483,647 caracteres, el tamaño max. de `Int32`, aunque esto no es del todo cierto), sino una propiedad de los `strings` en .net y otros lenguajes: son inmutables.

En cada interacción de tu bucle se esta creando un nuevo string en memoria, y esto está haciendo que sea extremadamente lento.

Para hacer lo que pides, debes usar [`StringBuilder`](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.text.stringbuilder?view=netframework-4.8), que representa una string *mutable* . Mira este ejemplo:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
{
     sb.Append("lore");
}
Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
```

Al usar `StringBuilder` no estás creando un `string` en cada interacción, y funcionará como esperas.